# Unable to play hls video with Cloudfront Signed Cookies on Android

Tags: android, react-native, cookies, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to get hls video working with signed cookies on Android. I'm using [react-native-video](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-video) for playing videos.

The hls video works fine without signed cookies. But it's not playing with signed cookies. It's also working fine on web with signed cookies. But, unable to set it up on Android.

I tried [react-native-video-cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59363691/react-native-video-cookies) solution but it didn't work.

On web I used universal-cookies to set cookies with respective domain and path="/" as set in backend. And it works fine in the browser. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm getting - {"error": {"errorException": "com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 403", "errorString": "Unrecognized media format"}}

On playing the video.

Comment: I have the same error, did you solved it?

Comment: No, we end up not using signed cookies for android.